# Restoring a live tile to a static tile automatically after I remove its background agent

Tags: windows-phone-8, telerik, windows-phone, live-tile, background-agents

My app's primary tile has live tile capabilities. If however I turn off the live tile functionality, when I return to the Start screen, my app's primary tile is still showing the last state of the live tile.

I was wondering what I need to do in order to restore my app's primary tile to its static state as soon as I turn the live tile functionality off? At the moment, I need to resize the tile or remove/re-insert it to get this effect.

This is the code that runs when I turn off the live tile:

```
                // Remove the Background Agent for the live tile.
                ScheduledActionService.Remove("PeriodicTaskForLocation");


                // Update tile.
                RadFlipTileData extendedData = new RadFlipTileData()
                {
                    WideVisualElement = null,
                    WideBackVisualElement = null,
                    IsTransparencySupported = true
                };

                ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
                if (tile != null)
                {
                    tile.Update(extendedData);
                    LiveTileHelper.UpdateTile(tile, extendedData);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has done the trick:

```
  // Remove the Background Agent for the live tile.
  RemoveAgent("PeriodicTaskForLocation");

  // Delete tile.
  ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
  if (tile != null)
  {
                RadFlipTileData extendedData = new RadFlipTileData();
                extendedData.IsTransparencySupported = true;


                extendedData.WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/Icon.png", UriKind.Relative);
                extendedData.WideBackVisualElement = null;

                LiveTileHelper.UpdateTile(tile, extendedData);
  }
```